# JS merge 2 arrays and their individual values from a single index into a single index in 1 array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, join, indexing

I was wondering how i could achieve the above with the code i have below. So for example, when the data is joined i would have in an index in the new array combinedresults something like [2.62, 460]. Both functions below are called through an event listener when the user clicks a button. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
var mouseDistance = new Array();
var timers = new Array();
var combinedresults = new Array();

//THIS FUNCTION CALCULATES THE DISTANCE MOVED
function printMousePos(e) {
    var lastSeenAt = {
        x: null,
        y: null
    };
    var cursorX = e.clientX;
    var cursorY = e.clientY;

    var math = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lastSeenAt.y - cursorY, 2) +
        Math.pow(lastSeenAt.x - cursorX, 2)));
    mouseDistance.push(math);
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on = 0;
    timers.push(t);
}
```

Comment: `var lastSeenAt = {x: null, y: null};` is causing the trouble I guess. Move this out of that function. Otherwise you just try to compute `Math.pow(null -  somenumer, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks, though actually im wondering how to go about implementing the logic above in the question.

Comment: Where's `prevX, prevY, totalTravelled` then, can't see where they're used in your code.

Comment: My bad, those aren't supposed to be in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move that `lastSeenAt`'s init out of the function. And assign new value at the end of the function.

To get combinedresults, use the shorter of `mouseDistance` and `timers`, and push the data into `combinedresults` should work.

```
var mouseDistance = new Array();
var timers = new Array();
var combinedresults = new Array();
// Init with both is null.
var lastSeenAt = {
  x: null,
  y: null
};

//THIS FUNCTION CALCULATES THE DISTANCE MOVED
function printMousePos(e) {
  var cursorX = e.clientX;
  var cursorY = e.clientY;

  // Don't calculate when x, y is null, which is the first time.
  // Or you can give lastSeen some other initValue rather than (null, null).
  if (lastSeenAt.x !== null) {
    var math = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lastSeenAt.y - cursorY, 2) +
        Math.pow(lastSeenAt.x - cursorX, 2)));
    mouseDistance.push(math);      
  }

  // Keep the x,y value.
  lastSeenAt.x = cursorX;
  lastSeenAt.y = cursorY;
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on = 0;
    timers.push(t);
}

// get combinedresults 
function getCombinedResult() {
  // Get the shorter length.
  var length = Math.min(mouseDistance.length, timers.length);
  var i;

  // 
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    combinedresults[i] = [timers[i], mouseDistance[i]];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Though what I really need is how i can merge the data in one index from the timers array plus the data in one index from the mouseDistance array into one index in one new array called combinedresults.

Comment: You mean, you want your function also do `combinedresults[n] = timers[n] * mouseDistance[n]` ?

Comment: Yes, something like if the timers array has a value 2.62, and the mousedistance array has a value of 500, I want to put both those data into a single array, so something like [2.62, 500], thanks!

Comment: Is that be done on another function, or you want it to be done in `printMousePos`? Also, can we ensure that `timers` and `mouseDistance` has same length, or `combinedresults`'s length is equal to either of them?

Comment: In another function. Yup, combinedresults' length will depend on the length of both the arrays timers, and mouseDistance, thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer with a new function at bottom, check if that suit your needs?